# ActAsTaggableOn in mongodb and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, acts-as-taggable-on

I want to adding tagging facility in my application . so, I am using acts_as_taggable_on : https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

I have added following line my Gemfile:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.2.2'
```

and when I add following line in my user model:

```
acts_as_taggable_on
```

It gives me this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_taggable_on' for User:Class
```

Kindly, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That gem isn't going to work with mongoid and mongodb because it is built to allow tagging using a relational database using active record.

The good news is that this is very simple to do in mongoid. Simply add a new Array field named after whatever you would have listed as being acts_as_taggable_on. If you also have acts_as_taggable, include a generic tags field as well.

If you were going to have a model that looked like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :interests
end
```

You would build it like this with mongoid:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :tags, type: Array
  field :skills, type: Array
  field :interests, type: Array
end
```

Then when you wanted to save a tag, lets say as an interest you would do the following:

```
@user.interests << 'computers'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was useful, but how can I find all the user that belong to a specific tag? or all user belongs to any of the given tag ?
Just like : User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :any => true) in acts_as_taggable_on ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write form to take input into array?